# There is no ViewData item of type IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'DCResults'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have looked into this problem on other questions on Stackoverflow but none that I have found seem to be the right version of the problem for this code.

I thought that it might be because the list in the model is the same as the one in the controller.
Here is my Controller code:

```
String[] excelSheets = new String[dt.Rows.Count];
                    int t = 0;

                    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        excelSheets[t] = row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                        t++;
                    }
                    //TODO:Lägga till varje column så att dom kan flyttas till vyn innan dom flyttas till denna innläggning i databasen.
                    OleDbConnection excelConnection1 = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);
                    string query = string.Format("Select * from [Sheet 1$]", excelSheets[0]);
                    using (OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, excelConnection1))
                    {
                        dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
                    }


                    if (fileExtension.ToString().ToLower().Equals(".xml"))
                    {
                        string FileLocation = Server.MapPath("~/Content/") + Request.Files["FileUpload"].FileName;
                        if (System.IO.File.Exists(fileLocation))
                        {
                            System.IO.File.Delete(FileLocation);
                        }
                        Request.Files["FileUpload"].SaveAs(fileLocation);
                        XmlTextReader xmlreader = new XmlTextReader(fileLocation);
                        ds.ReadXml(xmlreader);
                        xmlreader.Close();

                    }


                    o.DCResults = new List<string>();

                    for (int y = 0; y < ds.Columns.Count; y++)
                    {

                        string dc = ds.Columns[y].ColumnName.ToString();

                        o.DCResults.Add(dc.ToString());

                    }
                    DataSet exceldata = new DataSet();

                        exceldata.Tables.Add(ds);

                }
            }

            //TODO: Errormessage here:
            return View();
        }
```

And this is my view (where the error occurs when I try to make a dropdownlist with the list result from the DCResults list so that users can map each of the results to a column name that I get from the same model that I use for the list.):

```
@model BFProj2.Models.OurColumns

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Import";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Import</h2>

Firstname:

<body>
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(modelItem => modelItem.FirstName)
    @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => modelItem.FirstName)
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("DCResults",(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.DCResults)
    </div>
</body>
```

And here is my model where I get the list and the new column names:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Linq;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace BFProj2.Models
{
    public class OurColumns
    {
        public Guid ID { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Comment")]
        public string Comment { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Username")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Firstname")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Lastname")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Last activity date")]
        public DateTime? LastUpdateDate { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Abstract number")]
        public int AbstrNum { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Poster title")]
        public string PosterTitle { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Workshop")]
        public string Workshop { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Keywords")]
        public string Keywords { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Institution")]
        public string Institution { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Collaboration email")]
        public string CollabEmail { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("DCResults")]
        public List<string> DCResults { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: The only place in the code you have posted that references `ViewBag.DCResults` is your view, in order for it be output, you need to assign it somewhere first.

Comment: Also the name of the property your binding to should not be the same name as the `ViewBag` property

Comment: Okay, so how do I assign a property in the model for the viewbag? And how should I name the already named list, or should I use dc as the strings in the list are called?

Comment: Its a bit unclear what you are wanting. `@Html.DropDownList` posta back a single value but you binding it to `List<string> DCResults`. Do you want a single select or a multiple select?

Comment: I want it to show a list with all the column names and to be able to choose a single value from that list. Thanks for asking to clarify I have never used Dropdownlist before this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments, firstly you need a property in your model to bind the selected value to

```
public string DCResults { get; set; } // this will have the selected value
```

Assuming your controller generates a list of columns names (for example)

```
List<string> columns = new List<string>() { "Column 1", "Column 2", "Column 3" });
```

then you need to create a `SelectList` and assign it a `ViewBag` property

```
ViewBag.DCResultsList = new SelectList(columns); // note should not be the same name as the model property
```

Then in the view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.DCResults, (SelectList)ViewBag.DCResultsList)
```

Note the are other overloads for creating a [SelectList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist(v=vs.118).aspx) and for [DropDownListFor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlistfor(v=vs.118).aspx)

Comment: A bit confused. In my case the DCResults is the list created in the model that I add the column names from the excelsheet to. Am I supposed to make the viewbag property like this: 'ViewBag.DCResultList= new SelectList(DCResults);'?

Comment: You could do that, but the you need another property in your model to bind the selected value to (which in my answer I called `DCResults`). So add a new property (say) `public string SelectedDCResult { get; set; }` and then change the dropdown to `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedDCResult, (SelectList)ViewBag.DCResultsList)`.

Comment: The other option is (since you already have the collection in the model) is to forget `ViewBag` and change the dropdown to `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedDCResult, new SelectList(Model.DCResults))`

Comment: Still getting the error, am I missing something,or do I need to add the list to the return view, and also it always start by sending me to ViewStart?

Comment: @E.A.O.S, You didn't state what the error was, but if you using the ViewBag option and you post back and then return the view, you need to assign the ViewBag property again

Comment: An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in App_Web_sg4tvffe.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. This is the new error. Though the alternative with viewbag got the same error as before. This got a new one.

Comment: @E.A.O.S, That's an unrelated issue (I don't know what `App_Web_sg4tvffe.dll` is - I assume its you own project). You need to debug you code and see where the error is.

Comment: Okay, I will do that, thank you, you solved my problem with the DropDownList.

Comment: Problem was still in where the DropDownListFor, forgot that the    ViewBag.DCResultList = new SelectList(o.DCResults); was still needed, but in some other format, what do I make it instead of a ViewBag if I use the second option you mentioned?

Comment: Or rather do I still need to initiate the SelectList beforehand?